# Python Flask не формируется сессия на мобильных устройствах

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, сессия

Делаю небольшое web приложение с сохранением пользовательской сессии. На пк все работает как по маслу, а на телефоне просто не формируется. Пример кода:

```
if 'id_user' not in session:
    session['id_user'] = 'Идентификатор пользователя'
else:
    pass
```

Comment: А на телефонах точно нужна сессия?

Comment: Мне же нужно как то различать от какого пользователя пришел запрос